# why is my element not targeted when reload through AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using object literals on my project. I'm targeting selecting with jquery. It works fine the first time but when the part I'm targeting is reloaded with AJAX I can't target those element anymore. But I look into firebug they're there...
I'm even doing console.log() to test if my code works and it works but it just doesn't want to pick those. So in order for it to work, I have to refresh the entire browser.
Do you know what's the deal with AJAX dom reload and selectors.

I think it's something to do with the DOM reloading and redrawing itself or something along those lines...

Here is my code:

```
Module.editWishlistTitle = {
  wishListContent: $('.mod-wish-list-content'),
  title: $('.title').find('h2'),
  titleTextField: $('#wishlist-title-field'),
  titleInnerContainer: $('.title-inner'),
  editTitleForm: $('.edit-title-form'),
  submitCancelContainer: $('.submit-cancel'),
  notIE9: $.browser.msie && $.browser.version < 9,

 edit: function () {
  var fieldTxt = this.titleTextField.val(),
      editForm = this.editTitleForm,
      titleParent = this.titleInnerContainer,
      fieldCurrentTitle = this.title.text();

  this.titleTextField.val(fieldCurrentTitle);

  this.submitCancelContainer.removeClass('hidden');

  if (!this.notIE9) {
    editForm.css('opacity', 0).animate({ opacity: 1 }).removeClass('hidden');
    titleParent.addClass('hidden').animate({ opacity: 0 });
    console.log(editForm);
  } else {
    editForm.removeClass('hidden');
    titleParent.addClass('hidden');
  }

 }

 init: function () {
  var self = this;

  console.log(this.editTitleForm);

  //edit
  this.wishListContent.delegate('.edit-title a', 'click', function (e) {
    self.edit();
    e.preventDefault();
  });
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are replacing an element on the page, you are destroying the original reference to the element. You need to redo the reference to point to the new element.

Create a new method in your code that (re)initializes the references you need. Instead of adding them in the odject, set them in the method.

Basic idea:

```
Module.editWishlistTitle = {
  wishListContent: $('.mod-wish-list-content'),
  title: $('.title').find('h2'),
  //titleTextField: $('#wishlist-title-field'),
  ...
  ...
  initReferences : function(){
      this.titleTextField = $('#wishlist-title-field');
  },
  ...
  ...

  init: function () {
     this.initReferences();
     ...
     ...
```

And when your Ajax call comes back you just need to call `initReferences` again.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @epascarello, but how do you redo the reference to point to new element? This is where I get lost... do I have rewrite all the selectors again in the init() in my code? And I'm using delegate BTW... So normally targeting new element shouldn't be problem

Comment: Edited response based on your comment.

Answer (score 1):

After DOM ready, if you inject any data / class / id will not be available in DOM, so better you use live or delegate to get your new data access.

http://api.jquery.com/delegate/

Best to use delegate, that will take care your new data loaded after dom ready, that way you can avoid to refresh /reload your page.